# MSSQL - Update a table with a self lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I have a table as follows;

```
id, title, application_number, parent_application_number, parent_case_id
2, 'asd', 'P1234', 'lkjh', null
3, 'qwe', 'adsqwe', 'P1234', 3
```

I know this looks confusing, but I will try to explain it to the best of my ability.
I basically need to look at the current row's parent_case_id, and do a query to find out which row has this field as the application number, and to update the ID into parent_case_id.

So far I have this, could somebody point me in the right direction please?

```
UPDATE guest.exported_cases
    set parent = 
          (CASE a.child
               WHEN '' THEN ''
               WHEN NULL THEN ''
               else (select id from guest.exported_cases b where b.child = a.child)
          END)
    FROM guest.exported_cases a;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join` to look up the parent row for each child:

```
update child
set    parent = parent.id
from   YourTable child
join   YourTable parent
on     parent.child = child.id
where  child.parent is null -- Does not currently have a parent
```

This sets the child's parent column based on the parent's child column.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake whilst posting. I will update the OP now.